# How can we initialize a parametrized constructor as default for a string?

Tags: c++, string, constructor, class-constructors

For an integer we can do it as

```
class A{
  int a;
public:
  A(int x = 0){ a = x; }
};
```

Comment: _"and I am a die hard Manchester United Fan"_ I've never understood this. You live on the other side of the world. Have you ever even been to Manchester? lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is difficult to understand exactly what you are asking.  I *think* you are asking how to specify a default value for a `std::string` parameter.  If that is the case, you can do it like this:

```
class A{
  string a;
public:
  A(string x = ""){ a = x; }
};
```

or:

```
class A{
  string a;
public:
  A(const string &x = string()){ a = x; }
};
```

Though, in either case, you should be initializing the `a` member using the constructor's **member initialization list** instead of the constructor's body:

```
class A{
  string a;
public:
  A(string x = "") : a(x) { }
};
```

```
class A{
  string a;
public:
  A(const string &x = string()) : a(x) { }
};
```